# Android get id for an edit text field from a context xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity called PeopleActivity, with a layout xml of activity_people.xml.

This activity is using the Android Studio Navigation Drawer Activity template.

I have a list view in the content_people.xml file named people_list.  When I attempt to associate this control in the back end, it is unable to find the id.  I am attempting it as:

```
peopleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.people_list);
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:  Did an update to the code section to reflect the correct control referenced.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare your listview like this:

```
peopleSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.people_list);
```

not as EditText

Comment: Zainal, thank you for your comment.  You would be correct; however, the R.id.people_list doesn't work.  I have two controls, a list view and edit test, I just grabbed the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  You cannot use capital letters in the naming of your controls.  Once I fixed this, everything worked fine.